# Custom IServiceProviderFactory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I wrote a custom `IServiceProviderFactory` and installed it in `Program.cs` of a new app like this:

```cs
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new PropertyInjectingContainerFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

It does lead to the correct configure function in `Startup.cs` getting called:

```cs
   public void ConfigureContainer(PropertyInjectingContainerFactory.Builder builder)
   {
        builder.AddInjectAttribute<InjectDependencyAttribute>();
   }
```

However, my created container only ever resolves two services: `IConfiguration` and `IHost`.

Everything else is resolved by the default container apparantly (for instance a service like `ILogger<T>` on a controller). What do I do wrong?

Here's the code for my custom factory - and please understand that I probably should be using an existing third-party container, but I also want to understand how this all fits together.

```cs
public class PropertyInjectingContainerFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<PropertyInjectingContainerFactory.Builder>
{
    public Builder CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return new Builder(services);
    }

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(Builder containerBuilder)
    {
        return containerBuilder.CreateServiceProvider();
    }

    public class Builder
    {
        internal readonly IServiceCollection services;

        internal List<Type> attributeTypes = new List<Type>();

        public Builder(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            this.services = services;
        }

        public Builder AddInjectAttribute<A>()
            where A : Attribute
        {
            attributeTypes.Add(typeof(A));

            return this;
        }

        public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
            => new PropertyInjectingServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider(), attributeTypes.ToArray());
    }

    class PropertyInjectingServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider services;
        private readonly Type[] injectAttributes;

        public PropertyInjectingServiceProvider(IServiceProvider services, Type[] injectAttributes)
        {
            this.services = services;
            this.injectAttributes = injectAttributes;
        }

        // This function is only called for `IConfiguration` and `IHost` - why?
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            var service = services.GetService(serviceType);

            InjectProperties(service);

            return service;
        }

        private void InjectProperties(Object target)
        {
            var type = target.GetType();

            var candidateProperties = type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

            var props = from p in candidateProperties
                        where injectAttributes.Any(a => p.GetCustomAttributes(a, true).Any())
                        select p;

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                prop.SetValue(target, services.GetService(prop.PropertyType));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [Dependency injection document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#services-injected-into-startup), we can see that Only the following services can be injected into the Startup constructor when using the Generic Host (IHostBuilder): IWebHostEnvironment, IHostEnvironment and IConfiguration.

Comment: @ZhiLv I meant those few are the only services *in the entire app*, ie. even the services that get resolved in controllers or whatever. I clarified that in the question.

Comment: @John, did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same issue and .NET documentation is horrible.

Comment: @john, hoping you've figured this out since 2020 as I'd like to know too. I see exactly the same behaviour as you - I've also added ISupportRequiredService interface and still seeing the same.

Comment: @RichS Never figured this one out unfortunately.

Comment: @davija No solution I'm afraid. And yes, the DI part of ASP.NET makes this thing incomprehensible.